# patients with diabetes OR the patients with diabetes

Tags: definite-article, zero-article

To my knowledge, if we indicate diabetic patients as a whole, 'patients with diabetes' is grammatically correct rather than 'THE patients with diabetes'. I don't understand why because we have to put a 'definite article' in front of a specific kind of noun. It is not just any patients with any kind of disease, but with a specific kind of disease.

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about diabetic patients in general, no article is needed. If you are talking about a particular group of patients and need to specify the ones *in that group* who have diabetes, you would use *the.*